# append data in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to pass a list within a numpy array in order to calculate its variance as explained [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.var.html)

The example I use is this:

```
import numpy as np
A= np.array([])
newrow = [1,2,3]
A = np.concatenate((A,newrow))
print(np.var(A))
```

The example above works however I can't apply it to my specific case (see below)

```
import csv
import numpy as np

f = open("training_stats.csv", 'r')
customers = csv.reader(f)
header = next(customers)

#I've tried with and without the .astype
A = np.array([]).astype(np.float)

for row in customers: 
    birth_date = row[10].split("-")[0]
    print(birth_date)
    A = np.append(A,birth_date)
print np.var(A)
```

Here is the error message returned

```
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Here is what my list looks like:

```
1963
1975
1957
```

I know I could compute variance this way:

```
var = mean(abs(x - x.mean())**2)
```

However I'd like to understand what's wrong with this `numpy.array` and the type of data I'm passing to it.

Comment: Your birthdate is a string. Numpy is probably doing a reduce internally which doesn't handle object datatypes. After your for loop do the astype and see if the error persists.

Comment: @Satyadev If I try 'A = np.append(A,birth_date).astype(np.int)'  I get this 'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '''

Comment: Could you include a (shortened) sample of your file? There's probably a much easier way to extract the data. :)

Comment: I would suggest using `pandas` for such tasks. Not only does it have a nice `read_csv` module. It also handels different datatypes in different columns automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Array A holds float numbers(as you specified), and customers holds strings. You cannot add strings to an array of floats. You should do:`A = np.append(A,float(birth_date))`

Comment: I've tried this one as well but I get this error message 'A = np.append(A,float(birth_date))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '

Comment: I've integrated your feedback within the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After your for loop , do the following:

```
A = A.astype(np.float)
```

Your csv reader reads the values as strings and dumps into the numpy array.Even though you have declared a float array , the values are strings causing the problem.

Comment: it's actually creating a new issue 'ValueError: could not convert string to float: '

Comment: Can you paste the output of the following : A[0:2] , A.dtype and type(A) before the error appears

Comment: A[0:2] returns `1962
[ 1980.  1957.]
1948
[ 1980.  1957.]
1961
[ 1980.  1957.]
1949
[ 1980.  1957.]
1946
[ 1980.  1957.]
1960
[ 1980.  1957.]

[ 1980.  1957.]`

Comment: type (A) returns `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: Your numpy array structure does not correspond with the information posted in question. For example, try the following : A = np.append(A,'1967) , append a few more values and observe the structure of A. Can you post some sample info from the csv

Comment: A.dtype returns float64

Comment: trying to do this as suggested `A = np.array([])

A = np.append(A,'1967')
A = np.append(A,'1975')  
A = np.append(A,'1977')  

print np.var(A)` I still have this error displayed `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

Comment: No , after all the appends do the following : A = A.astype(np.float) and then do np.var(A) , you will not get any error.

Comment: the csv contains many columns, I extract the year of birth using `birth_date = row[10].split("-")[0]`

Comment: true, after all the appends do the following : A = A.astype(np.float) and then do np.var(A) it works and returns 18.6666666667

Comment: My best guess is that you have a value in the column that has a string value comprised of alphabets which cannot be converted to int/float as it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

after further research I've had empty rows within my list.
In order to fix the problem I've controlled the value of the row and if != '' then I've added the value to the numpy array, now it works

```
import csv
import numpy as np

f = open("training_set.csv", 'r')
customers = csv.reader(f)
header = next(customers)


A = np.array([]).astype(np.int)

for row in customers:
    birth_date = row[10].split("-")[0]
    if birth_date != '':
        A = np.append(A,float(birth_date))
print np.var(A)
```

Comment: Generally we recommend appending new values to a list, and converting that to an array at the end.  It easier and faster.